# java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException after finishing main code

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I have a main code

and after it finishes I get this error:

How can it be? it means a new background thread is opened?

How can i terminate all of them eventually?

```
2016-08-07 00:00:42 ERROR linqmap.nio.NIOSelector Unexpected error in select loop
java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at linqmap.nio.NIOSelector.runSelector(NIOSelector.java:627)
    at linqmap.nio.NIOSelector$5.run(NIOSelector.java:477)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-07 00:00:42 ERROR linqmap.nio.NIOSelector Unexpected error in select loop
java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at linqmap.nio.NIOSelector.runSelector(NIOSelector.java:627)
    at linqmap.nio.NIOSelector$5.run(NIOSelector.java:477)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-07 00:00:42 ERROR linqmap.nio.NIOSelector Unexpected error in select loop
java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at linqmap.nio.NIOSelector.runSelector(NIOSelector.java:627)
    at linqmap.nio.NIOSelector$5.run(NIOSelector.java:477)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed your selector while it was inside `select()`.

If you're trying to stop it, you should set a boolean that is checked every time around the select loop and then call `Selector.wakeup()`.

Note that the select loop has to cope with being woken up when there are zero ready `SelectionKeys`.